# Can I create column where each row is a running list in a Pandas data frame using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, list, data-science, aggregation

Imagine I have a Pandas DataFrame:

```
# create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'val': [5,4,6,3,2,3]})
```

Lets assume it is ordered by 'id' and an imaginary, not shown, date column (ascending).
I want to create another column where each row is a list of 'val' at that date.

The ending DataFrame will look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'val': [5,4,6,3,2,3],
                   'val_list': [[5],[5,4],[5,4,6],[3],[3,2],[3,2,3]]})
```

I don't want to use a loop because the actual df I am working with has about 4 million records. I am imagining I would use a lambda function in conjunction with groupby (something like this):

```
df['val_list'] = df.groupby('id')['val'].apply(lambda x: x.runlist())
```

This raises an AttributError because the runlist() method does not exist, but I am thinking the solution would be something like this.

Does anyone know what to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please explain this point? "I want to create another column where each row is a list of 'val' at that date" How are these vals defined per date?

Comment: For simplicity sake I did not include the day column. I mention in my post that they are ordered ascending by a date column that is not shown.

Comment: Each date keeps the vals from previous dates for a specific id?

Comment: Yes, each day keeps the vals from the previous day and the current day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['new'] = df.val.map(lambda x : [x]).groupby(df.id).apply(lambda x : x.cumsum())
Out[138]: 
0          [5]
1       [5, 4]
2    [5, 4, 6]
3          [3]
4       [3, 2]
5    [3, 2, 3]
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you explain why the final result has 6 rows even though there are only 2 groups?

Comment: @recentadvances you can check with what is `cumsum` ~ , it will return the cumulative sum ~

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. I also notice this doesn't work if you use `cumsum` method directly after `groupby`, you need to use it within an `apply`. Any idea why?

Comment: @recentadvances common bug for object